# C++ std::fstream how to move to a certain line and column of a file

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

So I have been searching on how to move to a certain line and column in a file , but I can't seem to find an answer . I want something like this :

```
std::fstream file("example.txt");
file.move_to( line number , column number );
```

Comment: I already knew that , and that is not what this question is about

Comment: then the question is unclear. If you want such a function you can write it. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I need to move to a certain position in a file , on a certain line , and a certain character. Also I'm asking for a function , I dont have enough time to write it

Comment: such function does not exist. though its 4-5 lines of code if you simply count line breaks and characters until you reach desired position.

Comment: you should rephrase the question a little. "I want ..." is not a question. You can read a reference about `std::fstream` to find that it doesnt have the method https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream. You can write such function. If you do not want that then I do not understand what you are asking for

Comment: @ibrahimmuhmudusmani, if I understand correctly, you want someone else to write this code for you because you don't have the time to figure it out yourself?  That's not what Stack Overflow is for.  It would be better if you tried to write it yourself then if you run into issues and you can't figure out why you can't make it work, post the code you used and what issues you are running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function can do just you want:

```
std::string GetLine(std::istream& fs, long long index)
{
    std::string line;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        std::getline(fs, line);
    }
    return line;
}
```

The above function gets the line at `index` (`index == 0` - 1st line, `index == 2` - 3rd line, etc.).

### Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string GetLine(std::istream& fs, long long index)
{
    std::string line;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        std::getline(fs, line);
    }
    return line;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fs("input.txt"); // fstream works too
    std::cout << GetLine(fs, 1);
}
```

### input.txt

```
This is
a
test file
```

### Output:

```
a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I need to go to a certain column aswell. for example if the column is 3 and "long long index" is 1 then the function would return 'h'

Comment: For column you can just say `GetLine(fs, row_index)[column_index];`. Note that indexes start with `0`, not `1`.

Comment: hmm , what does that snippet mean

Comment: `std::getline` gets a line of `istream`. Now in the above code, I am looping over the file's lines until I reach the `index`'th line. Then I am returning that line. For more info on `std::getline`, look up to [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Comment: Nice , it works :)